# Server side include (SSI) directives work in index.html but not in files in a sub-directory

Tags: html, server-side-scripting

I was wondering if someone could explain/have a solution for why my SSI's do not work if the file I'm including is back a directory. e.g.

- index.html
- gallery/pictures.html
- ssi-files/navigation.html

**This works when I use it in my index.html file:**

> ```
> <!--#include file="ssi-files/navigation.html"-->
> ```

**This does not work when I use it in my gallery/pictures.html file:**

> ```
> <!--#include file="../ssi-files/navigation.html"-->
> ```

Help in solving this one would be much appreciated.

Comment: From the [Apache Tutorial: Introduction to Server Side Includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html#additionalexamples):  `The file attribute is a file path, relative to the current directory. That means that it cannot be an absolute file path (starting with /), nor can it contain ../ as part of that path.`. So you might consider using the _virtual_ attribute instead of _file_ which allows you to `specify a URL relative to the document being served.` That's often used in footers where pages are nested in different directories (see "Including a standard footer" in that link).

Comment: No problem. Feel free to add that as an answer below, or whatever worked for you, and accept it when you can (you'll earn some more reputation points).

Answer (score 2):

Changing the code from

`<!--#include file="...`

to

`<!--#include virtual="...`

solved the issue I was having.

Thank you Dan.

Answer (score 1):

Files that use SSI (Server Side Includes) need to be named with an `.shmtl` extension. Therefore, if you have markup in your webpage calling `<!-- #include virtual...`, that file needs to be called `example.shtml`. This will let the server know what type of code to look for and how to read it.
[Server Side Includes ala' Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Comment: .shtml is not a requirement. You can add a `module mapping` which can be found under `handler mappings`. In doing this, you can add pretty much any file extension you need.